# Is there a way to access Google Workspace if Squarespace is the provider of said services?

Tags: google-workspace

I'm an IT Administrator and my client wants access to Google workspace.  They are currently with Squarespace who provides email through google workspace.  I've been in contact with Squarespace and they have been less than helpful when it comes to getting access to the google workspace admin console.  My client does not know if they have ever received log in credentials for google workspace, and I cannot contact google without an email address associated with the domain.  How can I resolve this issue?

I tried Contacting Squarespace to simply whitelist a domain, and they told me I have to log into the google admin console??  With what credentials?  I don't know.  Because Squarespace is in a federated relationship with google I thought that maybe they would have access but I guess not.